# Recibiendo un array pero lo está tomando cómo string PHP

Tags: php

espero se encuentren muy bien.

Tengo la siguiente función en PHP que se supone que debe estar recibiendo un array pero lo está tomando cómo string.

Alguien me puede ayudar encontrando el error por favor.

Este es mi código:

```
public function getCustomfielForSegment($arrIds) {

    $arrid = explode(",", $arrIds);
    $whereids = array();
    foreach ($arraid as $key){
        $whereids[] = $key;
    }
    $where = array("idSegment" => array('$in' => $whereids));
    $segment = /Segment::find(where);
    $arrIdContactList = array();
    
    foreach ($segment as $key => $val) {
        foreach ($val->contactlist as $key) {
            $arrIdContactList[] = (Int) $key ['idContactlist'];
    }

}
```

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me podría ser de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola. Explica a qué variable te refieres, ¿a `$arrIds`? Si es un array, ¿por qué haces `explode` sobre esa variable? Pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema. Si es posible muéstranos un `var_dump` de la variable problemática. Además, si es para usarla en una consulta del tipo `IN(lista de valores)` ¿no estás manoseando demasiado esos datos? Parece que usas algún framework, casi todos aceptan arrays como criterios para consultas del tipo `IN(...)` y otras.

Comment: Además, parecería que `$arrid` y `$whereids` son la misma cosa, en el hipotético caso de un `explode`, lo que tendrías en `$arrid` sería un array de valores. Pero como dije antes, podrías pasar perfectamente el array de valores como criterio para un `IN()` y ahorrarte todo ese proceso de `explode`, y de un bucle para obtener lo mismo que ya obtuviste con `explode`. Sospecho que con esto bastaría: `$where = array("idSegment" => array('$in' => $arrIds));` y que todo lo que hay antes de esa línea sobra.

Comment: Actualmente a función recibe una cadena de string, la parte por comas (,) y la recorre para guardarla en un arreglo nuevo.

Comment: @estrada No entiendo el problema.  Si la función ya te lo coge como string y está funcionando, ¿que quieres cambiar exactamente y porque?

Comment: El planteamiento es confuso. Si recibe un array creo lo puedes pasar directamente para que sea tomado como criterio de la consulta. Si viene como cadena separada por comas el explode te genera ya un array, no necesitas recorrerlo para crear otro array idéntico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, **usa tipado**, no estamos en 2015.

Segundo, como no usas tipado, nadie sabe que recibe esa función, puede ser literalmente casi cualquier cosa: nulo, número, objeto, string...
Podríamos quiza inferirlo viendo el lugar en que llamas a la función.

Por la primera línea, se espera recibir un *string* con una serie de IDs separadas por comas. `explode` divide un *string* en partes, que introduce en un *array*.

Podrías esperar un *array* o un *string*, sin tipar. En este caso pregunta el tipo antes de operar, cambia el nombre del parámetro, p.e.

```
public function getCustomfielForSegment($arrOrStrIds)
{
    $arrIds = [];

    if (is_string($arrOrStrIds)) {
        $arrIds = explode(",", $arrOrStrIds);
    } else {
        if (is_array($arrOrStrIds)) {
            $arrIds = $arrOrStrIds;
        } else {
            // ERROR
        }
    }
    // Ahora tienes un array con IDs o un array vacío
    // ...
}
```